# how can I resolve the mediapipe text to image machine learning using stable diffusion error Access denied finding property "ro.mediatek.platform" and

Tags: android, kotlin, mediapipe

I am using mediapipe stable diffusion text to image on device ml  but when I run my app it crash due to `logcat error -- Access denied finding property "ro.mediatek.platform"and fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 2753 (mediapipe/2753)`

I tried it with different approches. Also checked `manifest.xml` file and provide all necessary permissions